# C# what am I doing wrong ? Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll line 90 and 231

Tags: c#, prediction

I keep getting this error when I try to run the debugger Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
This is hypothetical reasons too here's my code it deals with predictions but whenever I try to run it I get the exception thrown, I had it working before but I don't know what happened but I've tried everything all of this is based off Jeff Heaton's books on prediction ML models

```
 namespace PowerBallPredictor
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;
    using Encog.Neural.Networks;
    using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
    using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
    using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
    using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
    class Result
    {
        public int V1 { get; private set; }
        public int V2 { get; private set; }
        public int V3 { get; private set; }
        public int V4 { get; private set; }
        public int V5 { get; private set; }
        public int V6 { get; private set; }
        public Result(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5, int v6)
        {
            V1 = v1;
            V2 = v2;
            V3 = v3;
            V4 = v4;
            V5 = v5;
            V6 = v6;
        }
        public Result(double[] values)
        {
            V1 = (int)Math.Round(values[0]);
            V2 = (int)Math.Round(values[1]);
            V3 = (int)Math.Round(values[2]);
            V4 = (int)Math.Round(values[3]);
            V5 = (int)Math.Round(values[4]);
            V6 = (int)Math.Round(values[5]);
        }
        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return
            V1 >= 1 && V1 <= 69 &&
            V2 >= 1 && V2 <= 69 &&
            V3 >= 1 && V3 <= 69 &&
            V4 >= 1 && V4 <= 69 &&
            V5 >= 1 && V5 <= 69 &&
            V6 >= 1 && V6 <= 69 &&
            V1 != V2 &&
            V1 != V3 &&
            V1 != V4 &&
            V1 != V5 &&
            V1 != V6 &&
            V2 != V3 &&
            V2 != V4 &&
            V2 != V5 &&
            V2 != V6 &&
            V3 != V4 &&
            V3 != V5 &&
            V3 != V6 &&
            V4 != V5 &&
            V4 != V6 &&
            V5 != V6;
        }
        public bool IsOut()
        {
            return
            !(
            V1 >= 1 && V1 <= 69 &&
            V2 >= 1 && V2 <= 69 &&
            V3 >= 1 && V3 <= 69 &&
            V4 >= 1 && V4 <= 69 &&
            V5 >= 1 && V5 <= 69 &&
            V6 >= 1 && V6 <= 69);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(
            "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
            V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6);
        }
    }
    class ListResults : List<Result> { }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileDB = @"C:\Projects\Predictor\db\winnums-text.txt";
            try
            {
                ListResults dbl = null;
                if (CreateDatabases(fileDB, out dbl))
                {
                    var deep = 27;
                    var network = new BasicNetwork();
                    network.AddLayer(
                    new BasicLayer(null, true, 6 * deep));
                    network.AddLayer(
                    new BasicLayer(
                    new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 5 * 6 * deep));
                    network.AddLayer(
                    new BasicLayer(
                    new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 5 * 6 * deep));
                    network.AddLayer(
                    new BasicLayer(
                    new ActivationLinear(), true, 6));
                    network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
                    var learningInput = new double[deep][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < deep; ++i)
                    {
                        learningInput[i] = new double[deep * 6];
                        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < deep; ++j)
                        {
                            var idx = 2 * deep - i - j;
                            var data = dbl[idx];
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V1;
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V2;
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V3;
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V4;
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V5;
                            learningInput[i][k++] = (double)data.V6;
                        }
                    }
                    var learningOutput = new double[deep][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < deep; ++i)
                    {
                        var idx = deep - 1 - i;
                        var data = dbl[idx];
                        learningOutput[i] = new double[6]
                        {
                            (double)data.V1,
                            (double)data.V2,
                            (double)data.V3,
                            (double)data.V4,
                            (double)data.V5,
                            (double)data.V6
                        };
                    }
                    var trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(
                    learningInput,
                    learningOutput
                    );
                    var train = new ResilientPropagation(
                    network, trainingSet);
                    train.NumThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
                START:
                    network.Reset();
                RETRY:
                    var step = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        train.Iteration();
                        Console.WriteLine("Train Error: {0}", train.Error);
                        ++step;
                    }
                    while (train.Error > 0.001 && step < 20);
                    var passedCount = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < deep; ++i)
                    {
                        var should =
                        new Result(learningOutput[i]);
                        var inputn = new BasicMLData(6 * deep);
                        Array.Copy(
                        learningInput[i],
                        inputn.Data,
                        inputn.Data.Length);
                        var comput =
                        new Result(
                        ((BasicMLData)network.
                        Compute(inputn)).Data);
                        var passed = should.ToString() == comput.ToString();
                        if (passed)
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            ++passedCount;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
                        should.ToString().PadLeft(17, ' '),
                        passed ? "==" : "!=",
                        comput.ToString().PadRight(17, ' '),
                        passed ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    var input = new BasicMLData(6 * deep);
                    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < deep; ++i)
                    {
                        var idx = deep - 1 - i;
                        var data = dbl[idx];
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V1;
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V2;
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V3;
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V4;
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V5;
                        input.Data[k++] = (double)data.V6;
                    }
                    var perfect = dbl[0];
                    var predict = new Result(
                    ((BasicMLData)network.Compute(input)).Data);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Predict: {0}", predict);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    if (predict.IsOut())
                        goto START;
                    if ((double)passedCount < (deep * (double)3 / (double)10) ||
                        !predict.IsValid())
                        goto RETRY;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key for close...");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
        static bool CreateDatabases(
        string fileDB,
        out ListResults dbl)
        {
            dbl = new ListResults();
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileDB))
            {
                var line = string.Empty;
                var separator = new string[] { "  " };
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == "Draw Date   WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP") continue;
                    var values = line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    var res = new Result(
                    int.Parse(values[1]),
                    int.Parse(values[2]),
                    int.Parse(values[3]),
                    int.Parse(values[4]),
                    int.Parse(values[5]),
                    int.Parse(values[6])
                    );
                    dbl.Add(res);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and this is what the output is

```
'PowerBallPredictor.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 
'PowerBallPredictor.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Projects\Predictor\PowerBallPredictor\PowerBallPredictor\bin\Debug\PowerBallPredictor.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'PowerBallPredictor.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PowerBallPredictor.exe): Loaded 'C:\Projects\Predictor\PowerBallPredictor\PowerBallPredictor\bin\Debug\encog-core-cs.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
'PowerBallPredictor.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PowerBallPredictor.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. 
'PowerBallPredictor.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PowerBallPredictor.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. 
The program '[6968] PowerBallPredictor.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing your code to see which parts trigger the error?

Comment: Have you run your code in the debugger? Using the debugger it should be easy to track down the line that throws the error. The error is probably that some `.Parse(...)` method is fed with a string that is null or empty, or that contains a value that is not numeric.

Comment: You should tell the line number as well, where you are getting exception.

Comment: also consider using arrays as this is a little bit wierd:  `public Result(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5, int v6)`

Comment: lol how exactly? I've tried everything I know, I wouldn't of asked for help if wasn't approaching the limits of my abilities -_-

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException event the first thing you do in Main to print the exception as it's being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is the most likely reason. You don't specify which version of .NET you are using, but in .NET framework 4.X (etc.) the following line will generate that exception:

```
int.Parse("a1");
```

In .NET Core, the exception will display as something similar to:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

So,... to your code. I believe the most culprit is the integer parsing you are doing in the `CreateDatabases()` method. You've got bad data in your text file, an alphanumeric value rather than an integer value. Change the `int.Parse()` to `int.TryParse()` or implement some improved data handling and that will remove the exception.